# R to find elements in a vector that their indices dose not exist in another vector

Tags: r, vector, find, match

I have a vector like the following:

```
VEC = c(4,8,8,8)
```

I also have an indices vector which tells me what elements in `VEC` I should ignore:

```
indx = c(2,4)
```

I want to get the index of the first element whos value is `8` but the index does not exist in indx array. how can I do that?

So basically i should get `3` as the answer. `VEC[3] = 8` (but the second 8 not the first one).

---

Here is another one
`VEC = c(1,3,5,3,3,3,3)` and here is the ignore list: `indx=c(1,2,4,6)`
Let's say I'm looking for values that match 3. The index that should be return is 5 because `VEC[1], VEC[2], VEC[4], VEC[6]` are in the ignore list and the first occurrence has index value of 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want the original index, then you can do something like

```
VEC <- c(4,8,8,8)
indx <- c(2,4)

which(VEC==8 & !(seq_along(VEC) %in% indx))
which(VEC==8 & !(seq_along(VEC) %in% indx))[1] #to get just the first
```

This is a bit ugly but might be more efficient

```
ok<-`[<-`(!logical(length(VEC)), indx, FALSE)
which(VEC==8 & ok)
which(VEC==8 & ok)[1] #to get just the first
```

Comment: I accepted this as the solution although @teucer answer is acceptable too, but this answer is correct without any modification. The arrays I'm using are short so speed is not that much of an issue.

Answer (score 3):

That might be more efficient

```
VEC <- c(4,8,8,8)
indx <- c(2,4)

VEC[indx] <- NA
which(VEC==8)[1]
```

Comment: Neat solution although I can't modify VEC as I use it elsewhere in my code. So basically I should store/restore them